# DHL is not working with production API url

Tags: magento-1.7, dhl

I'm stuck on this issue with DHL on Magento 1.7.1 :

**Symptoms:**

- If I use the test DHL API url I got the a correct response from DHL (https://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet)
- if I use the production DHL API url (https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet) the XML request is correctly created by Magento but I got no XML response from DHL.

**Details:**

- DHL response is empty
- an exception is trigger by and cached in `Zend_Http_Response`(579) and then caught in `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Dhl_International`(849):
  *Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message*

I contacted DHL but they say everything is correct on their side.

Any one is experiencing same problem ? what I should check ?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: hi i am searching with the same, do you have any +ve sign for the problem, please do share if any thing hope full

Comment: solution provided :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for question description this is a problem related to Magento < 1.8 and the fix is contained in this class `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl`

**Solution:**

Just copy this file`lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php` from Magento 1.8.1 in `app/code/local/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php`

**Details:**

Debugging Zend/Http/Reponse.php (`Zend_Http_Response`) and the response Header, I have found out that there is a difference in the processed response.

**Response Header for on 1.8.1**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 18:02:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerxmlpi-ea=705054885.47394.0000; expires=Tue, 22-Apr-2014 18:27:55 GMT; path=/
Via: 1.1 xmlpi-ea.dhl.com
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: TSfc8311=659c38c63b540f107d6b7aef1bc64ce8ee76bc99a82a71c35356aecf8b05127e488cf5af; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
```

**Response Header for on 1.7.0.2**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 18:04:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerxmlpi-ea=721832101.51273.0000; expires=Tue, 22-Apr-2014 18:29:26 GMT; path=/
Via: 1.1 xmlpi-ea.dhl.com
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: TSfc8311=da50e84622b1ff8f8df2403bc7a21df3a051ef21157ed05c5356af2a8b05127e528e9abf; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The main difference here is the presence of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.
This is causing `Zend_Http_Response` to use `decodeChunkedBody()` method that finally trigger an exception:
-- *Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message*

Now it is not clear to me if this is bug in Zend/Varien because it looks more a bug in the DHL response. ( if we use DHL Test API URL the response doesn't contains the guilty header entry )

If you look `read()` method in `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl` ( that is the only changed method in respect to Magento 1.7.1 version ) you will see Varien team has workarounded the issue just cleaning the header form that entry.

Comment: :: Could you pls help me, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/220467/57334      Changes not updated in DHL option.