# DHL shipping method is not working

Tags: error, shipping-methods, error-log, dhl

The DHL shipping method is not working in my magento Entriprise edition 1.12.0.2. I have enabled it from the Admin and it is displaying the error message specified in the configuration when trying to use it on the frontend.

I am getting the following error in the DHL error log:

> 2015-04-27T10:59:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
>   (
>       [0] => Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message
>       [1] => The response is in wrong format.
>       [__pid] => 30216
>   )

Please let me know if any one has experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I count down correctly, the `Magento EE 1.12.0.2` corresponds to `Magento CE 1.7.0.2`.

So yes, anyone experienced such a problem and worked around it by applying a more recent version of `lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php`, see [the original answer here on Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18725) as exposed by this site's search function.